# how to reduce using error message for every empty select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="deletePlace">
    <ul>
        <li class="pDeleteul">
            <label>Country</label>
            <select id="dpCountry">
                <option>choose country</option>
                <option>Damascus</option>
                <option>Aleepo</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="pDeleteul">
            <label>Cell</label>
            <select id="dpCell">
                <option>choose cell</option>
                <option>c1</option>
                <option>c2</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="pDeleteul">
            <label>Place</label>
            <select id="dpPlace">
                <option>choose place</option>
                <option>p1</option>
                <option>p2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deletePlace()"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**It is just 3 labels with 3 selections**

When pressing the delete button, if the user didn't select any option of any select, it should show an error message left of the empty selection.

I can do that by adding that error message left to every select and in my js check if the select was empty the make that error message appear but this makes me write more and more duplicate code. Is there any way using javascript (or jQuery) to make that error message dynamic create an appear to the using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('input[value=delete]').click(function() {
    $('.error').remove();
    $('select').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
            $this.parent().prepend('<span class="error">Error</span>');
        }
    })
});​
```

What each line does :

```
$('input[value=delete]').click(function() {
```

This attaches a function to the `click` event of the `delete` button (using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)) - uses [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$('.error').remove();
```

Removes any errors (DOM elements with the class of `error`) already present - uses [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('select').each(function() {
```

Executes a function on each `select` - uses [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$this = $(this);
```

saves `$(this)` for later use - if using an object multiple times its better (for performance) to "cache' it

```
if ($this[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
```

If the `selectedIndex` of the select list is `0` then execute

```
$this.parent().prepend('<span class="error">Error</span>');
```

uses [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add some HTML to the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) (`li`) of the current `select`

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QQAQJ/2/)**

Answer (score -1):

Try this-->

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(e){
        $.each( $('select'), function(){ if( $(this).find('option:selected').val().indexOf('choose') > -1 ) alert('error');    })
```

Comment: i don't know jQuery , but i used ur code as it is and my editor (netbeans) says that there is syntax error in it

Comment: and i hope that function just to use with delete button , ur function seems to work with every input in my website , right ?

Comment: yes correct; You can bind click event to specific button by putting an ID or css class for that delete button. And changing above code like `$('#button-id-attribute-value').on('click', function(e){...`

Comment: Syntax error. Indent your code correctly, and you will see why your code doesn't work. As it is, it's just unreadable.